# flow control of two buttons p and submit

Tags: javascript

There are two buttons. What I want is one should always and only give value 1, and the other one should take that value and add up. So, if first button `p` is 1 then `submit` should be 1. Next time I click `p` it should again be 1 but `submit` will be 2.

The problem is that I either end up with both having 1 or `submit` having 2,3,4,5 irrespective of what the `p` has.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var arr = ['shashank','kiran','sumanth','arun','rahul','akshay','kirannaik'];
    var i=1,k = 0, totalp = 0;
    var showName = function(){
        totalp++;
        console.log(totalp);
    };
    var presentIt = function(){
        p = 0;
        p++;
        totalp = p;
        console.log(p)
    }
    document.getElementById('present').addEventListener('click', presentIt);    
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', showName);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Attendance Sheet</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style>
        #present{
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
        };
        #displayName{
            display : none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="present">P</button>
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but the submit button is still iterating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want to keep the track of `p` click count on `submit` button. 
Look at the following example and hope it might help you.
This was developed on my understanding about your requirement.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var totalp = 0,
    p = 0,
    buttonState = 0;

  var showName = function() {
    if (buttonState == 1) {
      buttonState = 0;
    }
    console.log(totalp);

  };
  var presentIt = function() {

    if (buttonState == 0) {
      p = p + 1;
      totalp = p;
      buttonState = 1;
    }
    
    console.log(1);

  }
  document.getElementById('present').addEventListener('click', presentIt);
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', showName);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Attendance Sheet</title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <style>
    #present {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    ;
    #displayName {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="present">P</button>
  <button id="btn">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `p` click event always show the count as `1` in the console. But it will increment the `p` and used to show the `totalp` when submit is clicked. Because as I understand you always show `1` when `p` is clicked irrespective to it's count.

Comment: thanks but the submit button shows 4 if p pressed 4 times it should it should only show 1 and then if submit clicked then again p is clicked(no matter how many times)  submit should show 2

Comment: @shashank I updated the answer. Is this the requirement you want?

Comment: u are a pure genius sir... and i am such a dumb fellow controlling the buttons with adding aother variable and then will produce either 0 or 1 and execute the code respectively wow!!!!! thank u so much

Comment: @shashank Glad to help you. You can mark it as the correct answer if it helps.